# Find the distribution of random variable $XY+X+Y+1$

Tags: probability, random-variables

X and Y are iid with density $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}I_{(0,\infty)}$.

Find $P(Z\le z)$ where $Z=XY+X+Y+1$

my effort:
$P(Z\le z)=P((x+1)(y+1)\le z)=P(x\le \frac{z}{y+1}-1)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\frac{z}{y+1}-1}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dxdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-\frac{y+1}{z}dy=...?$

If I integrate it once more the result is $\infty$, which is obviously wrong - where have I done a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $y = \dfrac{z}{x+1}-1 \le z-1$ for any value of $x \ge 0$.

So, the bounds for the integrals should be $0 \le y \le z-1$ and $0 \le x \le \dfrac{z}{y+1}-1$.

Answer (score 2):

To make the math easier, I would define $X^* = X+1$, $Y^* = Y+1$, and observe that the PDF for each is now $$f(x) = x^{-2} \mathbb I_{x \ge 1},$$ with CDF $$F(x) = (1-x^{-1})\mathbb I_{x \ge 1}.$$  So $Z = X^* Y^*$ has CDF $$\begin{align*} \Pr[Z \le z] &= \int_{y=1}^z \Pr[X^* \le z/y]f_{Y^*}(y) \, dy \\ &=  \int_{y=1}^z \biggl(1 - \frac{y}{z}\biggr)\frac{1}{y^2} \, dy \\ &= 1 - \frac{\log ez}{z}, \end{align*}$$ and the rest is straightforward.